# Can iOS UI Automation be ran without real devices or simulators?

Tags: ios, xcode, logging, command-line, ios-ui-automation

I am able to get the UI iOS automation under control by using command line. But I would like to get the iOS automation running without real devices or simulators, but to determine if the tests are passed or not by reading the logs. Is it possible to do so? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI test framework use UI Testing in Xcode7, and CI System use OS X Server.